# Add comment then click edit comment doesn't close new comment box

Tags: bug, comments

I accidently clicked "Add comment" instead of "Edit comment" and so noticing my mistake, I clicked "Edit comment" and I had two comment boxes open. Surely only one comment box should be open (the one of the comment I'm editing) and the new comment box that I didn't want open should close by itself?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree this is a bug. The site doesn't know what your intentions were, so when clicking "add a comment", you commit to adding a comment. There also isn't a "Close" or "Cancel" link once you opened the box, so the site certainly shouldn't automatically close the box when you click "edit" on an existing comment.

Or rather:

- Should the new comment box also be auto-closed when you already typed some text in it?
- Should the new comment box be auto-closed when you click "Edit" on your comment under a different post than the one you started adding one on?

If you don't want to add a comment, simply don't click the "Add Comment" button.

Comment: Anyway, those open comment-boxes can just be ignored. If that doesn't work for someone, they can just reload the page.

Comment: Notice that there is a cancel link on the edit comment UI, but no cancel link on the add comment UI. If anything, a cancel link for the add comment UI seems like it would be easy enough to implement and would correct a UI inconsistency.

Comment: "If you don't want to add a comment, simply don't click the "Add Comment" button." but mistakes happen

Comment: @user the box being there does nothing of itself. I understand where you're coming from, but I don't think it needs to change. Adding a cancel link may be useful, but I wouldn't like the box to disappear when you click "edit" on another comment. At least not until both questions I asked are answered.